# Ошибка после обновления SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk, gradle

Обновил SDK, после чего и версии библиотек в gradle- файле. В результате студия попросила заменить версию у gradle проекта. Вот он :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
       // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Как видно, я заменил classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'` на `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`

Сделал clean/rebuild - > run и в результате получаю ошибку:

```
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location 'C:\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected 'C:\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19')
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\AndroidStudioProjects\labradoor\app\twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar (Не удается найти указанный файл)
```

Эту багу я чинил как-раз таки той строчкой, которую заменил на новую. Толкового ничего не нагуглилось. Сталкивался ли кто с этим головняком?

Comment: Кажись дело в каких-то зависимостях в app модуле... Что-то не туда куда-то ссылается... Попробуйте обновить версии используемых либ.

Comment: Android Studio не preview ли случаем?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб все либы обновил до последних/откатывал обратно - не помогает..

Comment: @Сергеич нет, AS 2.1.2

Comment: Попробуйте вот это: [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896916/observed-package-id-add-onsaddon-google-apis-google-19-in-inconsistent-locati)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо, но я так уже пробовал и результат все тот же=(

Comment: Ну а как у вас либа с твиттером подключена?.. Зависимостью или файлом? Если первое, то попробуйте прямо jar-ку в проект закинуть, коли уж её при сборке не найти

Comment: @ЮрийСПб первым делом так и сделал) Потом студия начала ругаться. Вообщем то мтеодом, которые скинули вы всё-таки получилось сделать. Правда после второго раза я комп перезапустил. Может это и помогло) Можете публиковать как ответ

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, написал) Надеюсь я правильно понял что именно помогло)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, это баги с SDK, как пишут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37648467/3212712) может помочь удаление всех версий Android SDK Build Tools 19.x. в SDK Manager. После этого должно остаться только Android SDK Buld Tools 19.1, кою надо заново установить. После этого может понадобиться перезагрузка студии/компа.